# machine learning & linear regression prediction error

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to predict answer by simple regression,but getting the following error:

> (' shapes (1,151) and (603,603) not aligned: 151 (dim 1) != 603 (dim
>   0)')

This my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset`enter code here`
dataset = pd.read_csv('pure_cotton.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,7].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,10].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)


#fitting simple_linear_reg to training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit([X_train], [y_train])

#predicting the test results
y_pred = regressor.predict([X_test])
```

Comment: Can you show the diemnsion of X_train and y_train

Comment: the dimensions of X_train & y_train are (603,)

Answer (score 0):

You should do some chengements:

```
regressor.fit(np.expand_dims(X_train, 1), np.expand_dims(y_train, 1))
```

And

```
regressor.predict(np.expand_dims(X_test, 1))
```

In order to avoid dimension problems, the first dimension, represents the number of samples, and the second dimension represents the number of features

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the `.values` from the `X` and `y`. You don't have to convert them to the numpy array. However, if you use the numpy array, you might have to use `np.reshape()` or `np.expand_dims()` to change the dimension of the array.